# Bootstrap table header group

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, html-table, bootstrap-4

I need simple suggestion on how to create picture table group highlet in bootstrap table help me.
I want Adult , Child , Infant  in picture like a table in bootstrap.

```html
<table class="table display product-overview mb-30">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Agent Name</th>
      <th>Groups Count</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="result in getresult">
      <td>{{result.Agent}}</td>
      <td>{{result.Groups}}</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use a combination of `colspan` and `rowspan` attributes in the `<th>` tags.

---

*Like this:* ***(Edited with all columns and example row)***

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    table,
    th,
    td {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <table class="table display product-overview mb-30">
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2">Agent Name</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Groups Count</th>
      <th colspan="2">Adult</th>
      <th colspan="2">Child</th>
      <th colspan="2">Infant</th>
      <th rowspan="2"></th>
      <th rowspan="2">Total</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Trans</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Total Transp</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Grand Total</th>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
      <th>Visa</th>
      <th>Total</th>

      <th>Visa</th>
      <th>Total</th>

      <th>Visa</th>
      <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>147</td>
      <td>1537</td>
      <td>69</td>
      <td>15870</td>
      <td>28</td>
      <td>6510</td>
      <td>1634</td>
      <td>376940</td>
      <td>1606</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>376940</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Let me know if you have any questions or if I misinterpreted anything.

***Happy Coding!***

Comment: Thanks for your support . how to add other columns ?? when i add after these group column its not show actually what i want like picture

Comment: @Johns OK, view the edits made.  I showed how to insert the other columns and an example of how to put the first row of data.  If I answered your question, please mark it as the accepted answer please.